# Difference between using pathForType and inflector.irregular in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We can customize the ember pluralization in two ways;

1. using 'pathForType' in RESTAdapter, like,

   ```
   App.GroupAdapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.extend({
      pathForType: function(type) {
       var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(type);
       return Ember.String.singularize(camelized);
       }
   });
   ```
2. By using Ember.inflector.irregular() in model

   ```
   Ember.inflector.irregular('group', 'group');
   ```

In both case it will make a call to 'group' instead of 'groups'. Is there any difference between both? which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one, but as a new developer starting to work on your Ember application - here is what I would expect.

`pathForType` used to modify the URL for one or possibly many resources. So, like if the Rest endpoint being consumed needs to have a `/blabla/type/` or something weird like that.

`inflector` is there to specify exceptions to conventions. So, something like `sheep` => `sheep` NOT `sheep` => `sheeps`